# Draw Gradient Label

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, paint

Is it possible to apply a gradient to label text?

Right now I am taking over a controls OnPaint and drawing the string of text that I want; however, this is to specific. I really want to make it so that the label itself gets applied the gradient colors I want. So in turn each character would have the gradient specified as the text has changed.

So instead of using the ForeColor I would apply a LinearGradientBrush. I am using WinForms at the moment.

**EDIT 1**

Here is the code that I am currently using. However, this only applies the gradient to all of the characters. I would like to change it so that each character in the string is applied.

```
// Draw the formatted text string to the DrawingContext of the control.
Font font = new Font("BankGothic Md BT", 48f, FontStyle.Bold);
LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(label1.Location, new Point(label1.Width, label1.Height), Color.Goldenrod, Color.Black);
e.Graphics.DrawString(label1.Text, font, brush, 0,0);
```

**Edit 2**

Here is what I did. I just extended the Label class and inherited OnPaint.

```
public partial class LabelEx : Label {
    public LabelEx() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        // Draw the formatted text string to the DrawingContext of the control.
        //base.OnPaint(e);
        Font font = new Font("Tahoma", 48f, FontStyle.Bold);
        LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height + 5), Color.Gold, Color.Black, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, font, brush, 0, 0);

    }
}
```

Which gives me a nice gradient text label.

Thanks!

Comment: Off the top of my head, try adding the text to a GraphicsPath and drawing the path with your brush.

Comment: If you're using version 4 of the framework the `FormattedText` object may be of help to you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752098.aspx

Comment: @SeeSharp this seems to be very specific to WPF. I don't have an OnRender method in WinForms.

Comment: @meanbunny Ah, you are correct - sorry I read too fast and missed you saying you were using WinForms. Sorry about that.

Comment: Please post as answer, not as an edit to your question.

Comment: @LarsTech Yeah, got a time limit for answering my own questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did. I just extended the Label class and inherited OnPaint.

```
public partial class LabelEx : Label {

public LabelEx() {
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    // Draw the formatted text string to the DrawingContext of the control.
    //base.OnPaint(e);
    Font font = new Font("Tahoma", 48f, FontStyle.Bold);
    LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height + 5), Color.Gold, Color.Black, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, font, brush, 0, 0);

}

}
```